# Node/Express angular 5 routing

Tags: node.js, express, routes, anchor, angular5

I am creating an application using angular5 and express 4.16. I have anchor tag on home page on click of which another component should be rendered (it should be redirected to that URL) but only URL changes.

Required code is below.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  import { NgModule }  from '@angular/core';
  import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
  import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
  import { TestComponent }   from '../test/test.component';


  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },

    { path: 'Test', component: TestComponent }

  ];

  @NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    // Import the DataService
    import { DataService } from './data.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {  
      // Define a users property to hold our user data
      employees: Array<any>;
      // Create an instance of the DataService through dependency injection
      constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
        // Access the Data Service's getUsers() method we defined
        this._dataService.getEmployees()
            .subscribe(res => this.employees = res);
      }
    }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import {TestComponent  } from '../test/test.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';
    import{DataService} from './data.service'
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        TestComponent

      ],

      providers: [DataService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**out put of folder through ng build /dist/index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>IndexV3</title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      <test-html></test-html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Node/Express server.js**

```
            const express = require('express');
            const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
            const path = require('path');
            const http = require('http');
            const app = express();

            // API file for interacting with MongoDB
            const api = require('./server/routes/api');

            // Parsers
            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

            // Angular DIST output folder
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

            // API location
            app.use('/api', api);

            // Send all other requests to the Angular app
            app.get('*', (req, res) => {

                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
            });

            //Set Port
            const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
            app.set('port', port);

            const server = http.createServer(app);

       server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on         localhost:${port}`));
```

**Output of home page as desired**

[Downoad screenshot Output after running localhost:3000 as desired anchor tag rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87yN.png)

**After click on anchor tag url changed but test component didnt rendered on browser**

[Downoad screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmSRZ.png)

**test.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({

      selector: 'test-html',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html'

    })
    export class TestComponent {
      title = 'app';
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
    <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h1>    
      </h1>  
    </div>

    <a   [routerLink]="['/Test']"  >test</a>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{employee.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**test.component.html**

```
        <span>yeeee</span>
```

**Project Structure**

[download project structure if required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGq0U.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the router-outlet. Take the template you have for app.component and create a new component with that template. Then make your app.component.html contain only

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Then in your app.routing.module.ts replace the object for your home route with:

`{ path: '', component: YourNewHomeComponent` },

more about router-outlet: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet